# How to display 3 <ion-card> per row that contains image and increment number by *ngFor

Tags: html, ionic2

I'm trying to design Ionic 2 HTML page that display 3 `<ion-card>` per row that contains fixed image size and increment number by using `*ngFor` such as shown in the picture.

[image: 3 <code><ion-card></code> per row]

**My HTML code you may need it**

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col *ngFor="let l of list1 | async">
    <ion-card (press)="delete(l.$key)">
      <img src="{{l.url}}"/>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a variable index which is incremented at each `*ngFor` loop.
Just add `let i = index` on your `*ngFor`. Your code edited :

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col *ngFor="let l of list1 | async; let i = index">
    <ion-card (press)="delete(l.$key)">
      <img src="{{l.url}}"/>
      <p>Image {{i}}</p>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

EDIT :

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
     <ion-card>
       Your first card content
     </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
     <ion-card>
       Your second card content
     </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
     <ion-card>
       Your third card content
     </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: Thank u @saperlipopette. But is there any way to display 3 cards per row ? Still I could not find the solution for Ionic 2

Comment: Its work fine without *ngfor. But when I tried to use *ngfor with ur code the cards repeated 3 times. I'm sorry if I bothered you but if you have free time please help me.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot it was in a *ngFor. You can try to override Ionic CSS to make a responsive grid of cards. Check this link : https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery

Comment: Just as an FYI, this works great on Android bt doesn't work on iOS

Comment: Could you elaborate ? What do you mean by "it does not work" ? How is it rendered ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add col-4 in your

this is the code:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let l of list1 | async">
    <ion-card (press)="delete(l.$key)">
      <img src="{{l.url}}"/>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```